# Fast Java library for circle recognition

Tags: java, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm looking for a Java library for circle recognition in a supplied bitmap.
My Java knowledge is too basic to implement eg. Hough transform efficiently (Java newbie).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the implementation in ImageJ, see [**here**](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/Hough_Circles.java).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for posting this answer many years after the fact, but that question was asked again in 2012 and then closed for being a duplicate.  As I said in my answer to that duplicate, I think the answer given here is overkill for such a simple problem, so is my simpler solution:

- Find all *connected* green blobs.  This is not completely trivial, but not that hard either.
- For each blob, find the point with the minimum x-coordinate and the one with the maximum x-coordinate and do the same in y.  Then you easily get the dimension of the bounding box for the blob.  If the x and y dimensions are different, you don't have a circle.  However, you should allow for some small differences since drawing a circle with pixels will result in an imperfect circle.
- Finally, if you have a circle, the center of the bounding box is (approximately) the circle's center and the radius is half the bounding box width.  You can draw such a circle and see how many of the green pixels fit in/out of your circle.  Again, you must allow for some imperfections.