# Circle recognition

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast Java library for circle recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556108/fast-java-library-for-circle-recognition)

I'm looking for a good Java algorithm/library to recognize a circle in a bitmap, and returns the coördinates of the center of the circle. The circle has one color. (eg. green).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I should say that I kind of agree that your question should be closed because it is a duplicate.  However, I don't quite like the answer provided since it's overkill for such a simple problem.

I would:

- Find all *connected* green blobs.  This is not completely trivial, but not that hard either.
- For each blob, find the point with the minimum x-coordinate and the one with the maximum x-coordinate and do the same in y.  Then you easily get the dimension of the bounding box for the blob.  If the x and y dimensions are different, you don't have a circle.  However, you should allow for some small differences since drawing a circle with pixels will result in an imperfect circle.
- Finally, if you have a circle, the center of the bounding box is (approximately) the circle's center and the radius is half the bounding box width.  You can draw such a circle and see how many of the green pixels fit in/out of your circle.  Again, you must allow for some imperfections.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can try with Neuroph Framework (Java Neural Network Framework).

http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/

Its very good api, but there is a catch. The recognition depends of "brightness" of images you are extracting circle from. You can contact author of this framework, he is phd student at University Of Belgrade, and teaching assistant at Artificall inteligence.

I hope i helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try implementing your own method by analyzing image data with a [Radon Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) and scanning the result image for horizontal lines.